# new \stdClass continua mostrando warning "Creating default object from empty value"

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código php

```
    $obj = new \stdClass;

    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $obj->get->$key = $value;
    }

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $obj->post->$key = $value;
    }

    return $obj;
```

O código funciona normalmente porém o warning do php

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\Users\User\Desktop\loren\core\Route.php on line 31

continua sendo mostrado, mesmo eu instanciando o `stdClass`

O que deve ser feito?

Comment: Qual a versão do php que tem a correr ? O `obj` tem alguma utilização no código acima do que mostrou ?

Comment: Não é mais fácil fazer: `$obj = (object) $_POST;`?

Answer (score 2):

O código que você fez faltou também dizer que os membros (`get` and `post`) também é do tipo [\stdClass](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.classes.php)?

```
<?php

    $obj = new \stdClass;
    $obj->get = new \stdClass; // faltou isso
    $obj->post = new \stdClass; // faltou isso

    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $obj->get->$key = $value;
    }

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $obj->post->$key = $value;
    }

    print('<pre>');
    print_r($obj);
```